# Sychronising work between two TFS servers

Tags: tfs, synchronization

We are some Devs working on an internal TFS-Repository. This TFS can only be accessed from within out network.

But we also have a test-lab which wasn't meant to, but ended up in being a development environment. Because we do not have any access to our company's TFS we used Microsofts tfs (visualstudio.com) instead.

We do not have the chance to change ANYTHING in our network-structure. So stuff like "just allow your test-machines to access your internal TFS would be of no help)

Some of our DEV-Machines can access both TFSs (internal and visualstudio.com) and some can only connect to the internal.

My idea would be to install some "sync" onto one of those dev-machines that can access both tfs's

What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bottom Line Up Front: There is no way to do what you are asking in a scalable and maintainable way**

The only way to fix this issue is for all developers to have access to the TFS server that they are using. However if you have a large budget for support and unlimited patience you can use the [TFS Integration Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe).

You can use it to sync both source and work items in a bi-directional manor. It will even maintain any relationships between source and wit.

Now the bad:

1. You will have to resolve all conflicts by logging onto the server running the migration.
2. You must have communication between the two servers
3. It's going to really annoy you

Another option would be to buy a commercial tool like OpsHub that will manage the synchronization and provide better conflict resolution. That will however be costly.

My advice (and I have done it every way before) is that you fix the issue not work around it. This is solvable in Healthcare, in banking, and in defence. I have been there your company is not special. Unless of course you are an insurance company and then you are too dysfunctional to save.