# Sync 2 TFS servers?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We have 2 TFS servers, one is inside the firewall, and the other one is outside the firewall. Because of security reasons, we still need to keep it this way. But the question is: is there a way to Sync these 2 TFS servers, say at every night?

Say we have servers TFS1 and TFS2, right now, we only want to Sync from TFS1 to TFS2, not bidirectional synchronization. If possible, we want to have complete synchronization.

I searched some time, but I could not find a good solution. It seems all recommendations are for old version TFS.

Are there any solutions for the latest TFS? existing products? Or, some information about API that we can use to make a tool for this?

Thanks

Comment: **What** do you want to sync? Source code only? Work items? Build definitions? Package management feeds? Unidirectional or multidirectional? There are certainly tools that can do this stuff, but it's going to be a nightmare to accomplish if you want a complete, bidirectional synchronization.

Comment: want to Sync from one server to another not bidirectional synchronization. If possible, we want to have complete synchronization.

Comment: If you only want unidirectional synchronization, the easiest way is to automate the process of cloning the instance. It's possible (I've seen it done before!), but it's a big pain. 
The bigger question you need to answer is why you need to maintain two separate instances. I can almost guarantee there is a better solution. If you update your question to include why that requirement exists, I may be able to offer you a solution.

Comment: It is because Top Management uses another software to add feature/story. This software uses TFS in the backend. However, top management's network is external to DEV environment, and company's DEV environment does not allow any external traffic hit internal TFS. So we have to setup a TFS externally, but then we need to sync this external TFS with internal TFS. Or, maybe there is a better solution? Thanks

Comment: You're describing a scenario where synchronization wouldn't even be possible. The two instances are totally isolated from each other. Something networking-wise has to change to allow sychronization to occur. If something networking-wise changes, suddenly your problem goes away entirely: Everyone can use the same instance.

Comment: Hi @urlreader, any update on this, have you came out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing changed with sync two TFS servers for the latest TFS version. Just as Daniel and many other expert suggested:

> TFS generally lives in 1 instance and 1 only. TFS is a production
>   environment for the development team. It doesn't make sense to have
>   two TFS systems and have them synchronize to make this separation.
>
> Having your teams work on two different TFS environments at the same
>   time is a very strange requirement.
>
> *[Source Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29139872/tfs-2013-to-tfs-2013-synchronization)*

The best solution in your case, negotiating with your IT team, set up a safe and stable way to allow your top Management users  to connect the internal TFS. You could also set up SSL for your TFS server to improve the safety. 
It will also save you a lot of time costs for maintaining two servers syncing.

If you insist on syncing two TFS servers take a look at this similar question: [Sychronising work between two TFS servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065010/sychronising-work-between-two-tfs-servers)

Another way is using VSTS instead of your external TFS. Microsoft has documentation on this exact scenario which can be found here: [Migrate to Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/migrate-tfs-vsts/?utm_source=ms&utm_medium=guide&utm_campaign=vstsdataimportguide) : Move from Team Foundation Server (TFS) to Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) and bring your data along.

**This link also contains the download link for the migration tooling which you will want to use**

> Currently the following versions of TFS are supported for import:
>
> - TFS 2017 Update 3
> - TFS 2018
> - TFS 2018 Update 1